# How to make CSS3 transition working for border-bottom property which starts from bottom to top

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have 2 examples below which display 4 links and hovering upon them display border bottom with ease effect.

In the Example 1 the border-bottom display from top-bottom. I have tried revering with the padding property which is there in Example 2, Its not consistent across the browsers and it does not works properly.

**Example 1: transition default functionality (transition from top-bottom)**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html><html class=''>
  <head>

  <style class="cp-pen-styles">
  body {
    padding: 50px;
  }

  a, a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  li {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline;
  }

  li a {
    border-bottom: 0em solid transperant;
    color: #777;
  }

  li:focus > a,
  li:hover > a,
  li:active > a {
      border-bottom: 0.313em solid #206E9F;
      transition: border-bottom .2s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition: border-bottom .2s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: border-bottom .2s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: border-bottom .2s ease-in-out;
  }
|
</style>
</head>
<body>


  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page">PAGE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact-me">CONTACT US</a></li>
  </ul>


  </body>
  </html>
```

**Example 2: transition from bottom-top (using padding - Compatibility issue with IE browser)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html class=''>

<head>

<style class="cp-pen-styles">
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

a, a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline;
}

li a {
    color: #777;
    padding-bottom:0.4em;
    border-bottom: 0em solid transperant;
}

li:focus > a,
li:hover > a,
li:active > a {
    padding-bottom:0em;
    border-bottom: 0.313em solid #206E9F;
    transition: all .2s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in;
}

</style></head><body>


<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#page">PAGE</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">ABOUT US</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact-me">CONTACT US</a></li>
</ul>


</body></html>
```

How to make CSS3 transition working for border-bottom property which starts from bottom to top.

Comment: Example 1 link: https://jsfiddle.net/nvdz98vn/1/ (border-bottom property transition from top to bottom)

Example 2 link: https://jsfiddle.net/3kd01ws9/1/ (border-bottom property transition from bottom to top)

Comment: What do you mean "from bottom to top" ? Like the second example ? Which seems to work, so what's the issue ?

Comment: It does not work in IE 10

Comment: Ah so it's a compatibility issue, you should edit your question it is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simulate your desired outcome by using [:after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) or [:before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) pseudo elements. This way you'll have much greater control over the desired effect (like adding various transforms).

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

li a {
  border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;
  color: #777;
  display: inline-block;

  padding-bottom: 3px;
  position: relative;
}

li a > .fancy-line {
  background-color: transparent;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0;

  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;

  -o-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, height 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, height 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, height 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, height 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, height 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

li a:hover > .fancy-line {
  background-color: #206E9F;
  height: 3px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#home">HOME <span class="fancy-line"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#page">PAGE <span class="fancy-line"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">ABOUT US <span class="fancy-line"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact-me">CONTACT US <span class="fancy-line"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does not seems to work in IE and Safari. Compatibility issue

Comment: What are the minimum versions for IE and Safari you want to support? I found [this helpful chart](https://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/) which shows which browsers support pseudo elements transitions.

Comment: See my edited answer. As I've changed to an actual element, **.fancy-line**, it now even works in safari 5.

Even though this solution is a bit messier as you need to modify the HTML it offers support for older browsers.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work in IE10? Is it the transition?

It's weird since this (and also the previous solution with the pseudo elements) works for me in IE 10 on Windows 7.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104426/discussion-between-n92-and-cosmin-ababei).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a pseudo-element and a transform rather than a border.

```css
  body {
    padding: 50px;
  }
  a,
  a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  li {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline;
  }
  li a {
    border-bottom: 0em solid transperant;
    color: #777;
    position: relative;
  }
  li > a::after,
  li > a::after,
  li > a::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: .313em;
    background: #206E9F;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    transform-origin: center bottom;
    transform: scaleY(0);
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
  }
  li:focus > a::after,
  li:hover > a::after,
  li:active > a::after {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">HOME</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#page">PAGE</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#about">ABOUT US</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#contact-me">CONTACT US</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does not seems to work in IE and Safari. Compatibility issue

Comment: I haven't used all the prefixes but you can add those yourself.

Comment: i have added browser specific properties, In IE 10, its not working directly by opening the file but working in codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoVzmb

Comment: No reason why it shouldn't but you could try `scale(0,0)` and `scale(0,1)` instead

Comment: yes, that works But if i copy past the code to inside existing HTML page, effect reverses (transition starts from top to bottom), maybe the existing styles which is causing the issue.